# Java ExecutorService invokeAll with different types

Tags: java, concurrency, threadpool, executorservice

I am using Java 1.7.

I am trying to execute two methods concurrently. However, each method has a different return type.

I have the following:

```
private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

private void executeConcurrentTasks(final boolean autoBookingEnabled, final TripDTO tripDTO, final ApprovalRequestDetails approvalRequestDetails, final ApprovalRequest approvalRequest, final QuoteResponse quoteResponse, final TripRequirementsResponse tripRequirementsResponse, final List<List<Evaluator>> evaluatorsList, final List<EvaluationApprovalTree> evaluationTree, final Long memberId, final Map<String,Object> properties, final HttpSession session) {

    List<Callable<?>> tasks = Arrays.asList(
        new Callable<BookServicesResponse>() {
            public BookServicesResponse call() throws Exception {
                BookServicesResponse autoBookResponse = bookServices(autoBookingEnabled, tripDTO, approvalRequestDetails, approvalRequest, quoteResponse, memberId, properties, session);
                return autoBookResponse;
            }
        },
        new Callable<ApprovalResponse>() {
            public ApprovalResponse call() throws Exception {
                ApprovalResponse approvalResponse = submitApproval(approvalRequest, tripDTO, tripRequirementsResponse, evaluatorsList, evaluationTree, memberId, properties, session);
                return approvalResponse;
            }
        });

    List<Future<?>> futures = executorService.invokeAll(tasks); // compile error
    
    for (Future<?> future : futures) {
        try {
            Object obj = future.get();
            if (obj instanceof BookServicesResponse) {
                // ...
            } else if (obj instanceof ApprovalResponse) {
                // ...
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Compile error:

[image]

**Question**

Is there a generic way to handle the call of the two methods, so that the returned list of futures each have a different object?

Comment: If you're going to put them all into a list, then perhaps you should use `List<Callable<Object>>` (and of course instantiate your callables with `new Callable<Object>(){...}`. That wouldn't be the worst part anyway, because you already have to cast. As far as typing goes, I think `invokeAll` is best suited for uniformly typed callables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work the way you tried because `invokeAll` expects a parameter of type `List<? extends Callable<T>>` and not  `List<? extends Callable<? extends T>>`. You could consider this a downside of the API.

In order to get around this, you can use a `List<Callable<Object>>` or use a common superclass of `BookServicdsResponse` and `ArrovalResponse` (I'll use `Response` in this example) :

```
List<Callable<Response>> tasks = Arrays.asList(
        new Callable<Response>() {
            public Response call() throws Exception {
                BookServicesResponse autoBookResponse = bookServices(autoBookingEnabled, tripDTO, approvalRequestDetails, approvalRequest, quoteResponse, memberId, properties, session);
                return autoBookResponse;
            }
        },
        new Callable<Response>() {
            public Response call() throws Exception {
                ApprovalResponse approvalResponse = submitApproval(approvalRequest, tripDTO, tripRequirementsResponse, evaluatorsList, evaluationTree, memberId, properties, session);
                return approvalResponse;
            }
        });

    List<Future<Response>> futures = executorService.invokeAll(tasks); // compile error
```

You can also use an "unsafe" cast like this:

```java
List<Future<?>> futures = executorService.invokeAll((List<Callable<Object>>) tasks);
```

As you would only retrieve elements from the `Callable`s, this would not cause unwanted `ClassCastException`s.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the best solution, and it doesn't actually answer the question how to use generics to have a list of different callables. But I ended up using two separate Callables and Futures.

```
    Callable<BookServicesResponse> taskBook = new Callable<BookServicesResponse>() {
            public BookServicesResponse call() throws Exception {
                BookServicesResponse autoBookResponse = bookServices(autoBookingEnabled, tripDTO, approvalRequestDetails, approvalRequest, quoteResponse, memberId, properties, session);
                return autoBookResponse;
            }
        };

    Callable<ApprovalResponse> taskApprove = new Callable<ApprovalResponse>() {
            public ApprovalResponse call() throws Exception {
                ApprovalResponse approvalResponse = submitApproval(approvalRequest, tripDTO, tripRequirementsResponse, evaluatorsList, evaluationTree, memberId, properties, session);
                return approvalResponse;
            }
        };

    Future<BookServicesResponse> futureBook = executorService.submit(taskBook);
    Future<ApprovalResponse> futureApprove = executorService.submit(taskApprove);
```

Comment: Looks good. The other approach seemed complicated. You could create a response interface and extend it with both response classes. But there is probably no common interface. So you will end up casting response objects. Btw the code from your question will work if you just replace <?> with <Object>.